# Chrome extension: When to read tag in <head>

Tags: events, google-chrome-extension, html-head

I'm writing a Google chrome extension in which I parse the `<head>` tags of any page loaded and look for a specific `<meta>` tag. A content script is used to communicate with the site, the actual logic is then done in a background script.

The question is when the background script should ask the content script to check the `<meta>` tags. `chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded` seems to be on the safe side, but I found that often this event is fired multiple times across when loading a page. Also, the `<head>` might be available before `chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded` hits. That all brings me to the question:

How do I best check when the `<head>` section of a page is loaded?

Comment: `onDOMContentLoaded` should be fired only once per frame. If you're only interested in the top-level frame, check whether `details.frameId === 0`. If it is fired more than once per page load, then it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're injecting a content script into all pages anyway the task can be done inside it instead of always waiting for the page to be completely loaded (could take a long time depending on the connection speed and other factors).

Inject the content script at document load start and use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) attached to `document.head` to get the result *immediately as it's inserted into DOM* during page load process. The observer will look only at direct children of `HEAD` element so it won't hurt performance.

Some sites may add `meta` elements after the page is loaded - this will be caught by the observer.

- manifest.json:

  ```js
   "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  ```
- content.js:

  If `HEAD` is present, look for the required `meta` element, otherwise wait for `HEAD` to be inserted.

  ```js
  if (document.head) {
      examineHead();
  } else {
      new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          if (document.head) {
              this.disconnect();
              examineHead();
          }
      }).observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true});
  }

  function examineHead() {
      var nodes = document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta');
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
          var n = nodes[i];
          if (reportMetaNode(n)) {
              return;
          }
      }
      observeHead();
  }
  ```

  Observe `document.head` and check each new element if it's the one.

  ```js
  function observeHead() {
      new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
              var nodes = mutations[i].addedNodes;
              for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
                  var n = nodes[j];
                  if (n.localName == 'meta') {
                      if (reportMetaNode(n)) {
                          this.disconnect();
                          return;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }).observe(document.head, {childList: true});
  }
  ```

  For example let's look for `<meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="......">` and send a message to the background script with the value of `content` attribute.

  ```js
  function reportMetaNode(n) {
      console.log(n, n.outerHTML);
      if (n.name == "twitter:app:id:googleplay") {
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({gotMeta: n.content});
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

  You may want to also process other types of mutations like `characterData` and `attributes` because some sites may change or add the element in separate steps (createElement, setAttribute, append the child text node and so on), in which case the observer callback will be a bit more complex and `subtree: true` will be needed in `observe()` parameters.